# How do I print from Android through my LAN?

Tags: printing

I have a HP f380 printer, which doesn't have wifi connectivity. I managed to share the printer through a computer used as printer server and print to it from different computers. Now how do I print to it by using my android device?

I found HP ePrint and Google's Cloud print, but they tend to go over the internet to connect to my printer, which is quite the detour since I'm on the same network as the printer anyways. So is there a way to print directly to the printer from my Android device?

Answer (score 0):

I've used the app "HP print service plugin" to print to my HP printer that's on the network, and it doesn't seem to use the Internet. The plugin was preinstalled on my device, and may not be compatible with your device, but you can have a look here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hp.android.printservice

Oh, and the plugin seems to support USB OTG too.